# Do I have to call mmap() for each process using a resource?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

I am trying to implement an application where many different processes access the same shared resource.  I would like to just `mmap()` once with first thread that reaches the resource [with proper synchronization of course].  The virtual address that is returned can then be shared across threads.

But I remember learning each process has it's own virtual address space in the Linux kernel, so the virtual address that is returned may not be valid for all threads.  Is this understanding correct?  Is there a way to to avoid multiple `mmap()` calls?

Comment: [Threads will share memory mappings; Processes will not.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Comment: " so the virtual address that is returned may not be valid for all threads" Address spaces are specific to processes. All addresses that are valid for one thread in the process are also valid for all other threads in that process.